# NoMethodError in #show view. Undefined method 'latitude'. Geocoder to get lat and long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, google-geocoder, nomethoderror, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to use Geocoder to populate the latitude and longitude for a given address of a restaurant inputed by the user.  My show page is giving me the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Restaurants#show

undefined method `latitude' for #<Restaurant:...
```

I've run:

```
$rails generate latlong migration latitude:float longitude:float
$rake db:migrate
```

I've updated the restaurant params to include latitude and longitude.

The part referencing url in the show file looks like this:

```
<p>
<strong>Where's it at?</strong>
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@restaurant.latitude}%2C#{@restaurant.longitude}" %>

</p>
```

Here's my migrate file:

```
class Latlong < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :restaurants, :latitude, :float
    add_column :restaurants, :longitude, :float
  end
end
```

and my model looks like this:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    mount_uploader :menu, MenuUploader 

    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode  

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made wrong migration, so:

- Run `rake db:rollback` - to return back and have clean DB.
- Run `rails g migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToRestaurants latitude:float
  longitude:float` - proper migration (due to gem documentation you
  have to add new columns to the existing model, not create almost
  separate and new table in DB).
- Run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Thank you - I have other params associated with the restaurant (address, phone number, etc.) Will the rollback, clear those as well? or only the last migrate?

Comment: If the wrong migration (with Geo) is your very last migration you can run `rake db:rollback STEP=1` to undo only this last migration you've maid.

Comment: And also (for better understanding of Geocoder gem) read [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast).

Comment: Huge help...so the name of the migration has to be structured as such: "AddNewmigrationToExisting"?